# SQL - Min Function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

My question is Write an SQL query that will determine which is the least expensive venue that will accommodate 120 people.

The Code i wrote

```
select v.venuename, min(v.costperday)
from venues v 
where v.venuecapacity = 120
Group By v.venuename;
```

I am still getting both the answers and not the Least one.

But if i remove V.venueName from the select function.....i get the correct answer!

Why is that so ?

Your help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It is not possible that selecting one more field changes result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the same field in the select list, thus the min will be computed for each of them not overall items

Comment: I didn't. Wouldn't know why. Your answer makes sense.

Comment: I did :) Because values in `select` list has nothing to do with rows count returned. Everything depends on `group by` value.

Comment: `You include the same field in the select list` and by the same field I mean the field in group by clause. I want to answer exactly what the question wanted, (why he get that result), but solution is sth else, he should remove the field from group by to get the result

Comment: If you DO NOT `include the same field in the select list` the min value will still be computed for each grouped `venuename` if this value is in `group by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT venuename, 
           costperday,
           min(costperday) over () as min_cost,
    FROM venues
    WHERE venuecapacity = 120
) v
WHERE v.min_cost = v.costperday
```

Or using a subselect:

```
SELECT *
FROM venues
WHERE venuecapacity = 120
AND costperday = (SELECT min(v2.costperday) 
                  FROM venues v2
                  WHERE v2.venuecapacity = 120)
```

You might want to use venuecapacity `>= 120` in case there are venues that accomodate more than 120 people but are still cheaper than others that only allow exactly 120 people

Answer (score 0):

```
select v.venuename, min(v.costperday)
from 
(
  select venuename, costperday
  from venues
  where v.venuecapacity = 120) v
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you select the lowest cost per day per venue if you include the name. In fact, the whole grouping is useless in this table as long as venuename is unique.

To get the venue with the lowest price use something like this:

```
select venuename, costperday
from
  venues v
where
  v.venuecapacity = 120 and
  v.costperday = (select min(costperday) from venue vs where va.venuecapacity = 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

```
SELECT venuename
  FROM (SELECT venuename, costperday, MIN(costperday) OVER () mincost
          FROM venues
         WHERE venuecapacity >= 120) q
 WHERE q.costperday = q.mincost;
```

Use >= 120, because you might not have any venues that have exactly 120 capacity, and you want all venues that can handle *at least* 120. Your requirements only state that the venue be able to accommodate 120 people, not that it handle exactly 120 people.

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE, can do

```
WITH minquery AS
 (SELECT min(costperday) AS mincost
  FROM venues
  WHERE venuecapacity>=120)
SELECT venuename, venuecapacity, costperday
  FROM venues 
  WHERE costperday=minquery.mincost AND venuecapacity>=120;
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is Write an SQL query that
>   will determine which is the least
>   expensive venue that will accommodate
>   120 people.

In SQL Server I would use `select top 1... order by`

```
select top 1 v.venuename, v.costperday
from venues v 
where v.venuecapacity = 120
order by v.costperday
```

Goggling a bit I found this syntax for MySQL and Oracle that looks like they will work but untested by me.

MySQL

```
select v.venuename, v.costperday
from venues v 
where v.venuecapacity = 120
order by v.costperday 
limit 1
```

Oracle

```
select v.venuename, v.costperday
from (select v.venuename, v.costperday
      from venues v 
      where v.venuecapacity = 120
      order by v.costperday
     )
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul Bhatia

there is one more solution we can use..

```
select v.venuename, 
       min(v.costperday) 
 from venues v  
 where v.venuecapacity >= 120 
 Group By v.venuename
 having min(v.costperday) = (
       select min(costperday)
       from venues 
       where venuecapacity >= 120 );
```